# Angular2 paths for all named router outlets

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm back with another angular2 question.

My project's unique characteristic is that I have a tabbing mechanism, where each tab is a different named router-outlet.
The goal is to include about 1k paths, so every excess line of code is an issue.

As is, I create a different routing file for each named outlet that includes the same paths and the only change is the outlet's name

```
    path: 'myPath',
    outlet: 'tabX',
    component: ProxyRouteComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: 'pathToModule#ModuleName'
        },
    ],
```

Is there a way I can create "global" routing file that every named router will have access to?

The next best option is to create a mechanism that auto-generates those files.

Thank you very much in advance!
Dimitris